# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, mavlink

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dumb or not, is it possible to communicate to a Computer running ROS using MAVlink and Qcontrol to designate waypoints? Is it also possible to alter the course through computer vision?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12546/ros-navigation/) by [Just Asking](https://answers.ros.org/users/1597/just-asking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Just Asking](https://answers.ros.org/users/1597/just-asking/) on 2012-01-07**:
I just wondered if you could communicate with a computer running ROS using MAVlink. I now need to know how the computer will navigate upon receiving commands.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-01-06**:
@Just Asking: I corrected punctuation but actually still don't understand what's being asked about. Could you please specify the hardware setup you're interested in and clarify what functionality should be realized by which party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a little punctuation to make your question clear.

Theoretically, you could have a ground station running QGroundControl communicate to a mobile computer running ROS and [serial_mavlink_ros](https://github.com/pixhawk/mavlink-ros-pkg/tree/master/serial_mavlink_ros)

Unfortunately, the message that comes out of serial_mavlink_ros is a MAVLINK packet wrapped in a ROS message, so you'd probably need to write your own node to decode it and listen for waypoint commands.

I don't understand your question about computer vision. In general, computer vision is very difficult, particularly if you're operating in an outdoor environment. I doubt that it's possible to replace an IMU with a camera.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Just Asking](https://answers.ros.org/users/1597/just-asking/) on 2012-01-08**:
The next thing to do is to communicate to the Ardupilot V2 IMU for sensor input and movement output using ROS. Other people may have already done so.

**Comment by [Just Asking](https://answers.ros.org/users/1597/just-asking/) on 2012-01-08**:
I guess I might as well use MAVCONN since it already has computer vision. I also found that using ROS at this stage can be a bit too bulky, especially with decoding each MAVlink packet being received. I can add ROS to add some flexibility in the program though.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-07**:
I know that GPSs are supported via gpsd and the gpsd_client package, and laser scanners are supported. I think some IMUs and sonars may be supported as well.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-07**:
The Kinect doesn't function well outdoors, and the maximum range is 4-5 meters. If you want navigation, you'll have to figure out which sensors are appropriate to your application and which navigation nodes you'll need to process their input.

**Comment by [Just Asking](https://answers.ros.org/users/1597/just-asking/) on 2012-01-07**:
Besides the communication, after receiving commands, how does the ROS computer navigate?

**Comment by [Just Asking](https://answers.ros.org/users/1597/just-asking/) on 2012-01-07**:
Thank you very much. The last part of the question is just asking if a Kinect and/or auditional sensors can be added for object avoidance. Sorry about my punctuation, grammar was never my strongpoint.